# How to create mysql volume which exists even if i remove the docker container

Tags: mysql, database, docker, containers

I created docker container with mysql using -v option:

```
-v /storage/mysql1/mysql-datadir:/var/lib/mysql
```

When i removed container i lost database saved in `/var/lib/mysql` . 
How can i create mysql container with -v option (to see everything from the host) and not lost the data?

Comment: Is there still content in /storage/mysql1/mysql-datadir on the host after stopping the instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried restarting the `mysql` service in your host?

This is something like restoring MYSQL db from physical file.

When you perform db operations inside container, it saves real-data and indexes in `/var/lib/mysql` path or the path that you specify while installing.

But, for Host machine, MYSQL service still does not know about the change.

Restart the MYSQL service by `service mysql restart`.

Additionally check the owner and permission in the MYSQL data folder like below:

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
sudo chmod -R 660 /var/lib/mysql/
sudo chown -R mysql.mysql /var/log/mysql
```

While running container, mount `/var/log/mysql` as well along with data folder.

Comment: i run the container using: 
docker run --name=mysql --net=kajsnetwork mysql:v2 -v /var/lib/mysql - then i enter the container and create database. No files was created in /var/lib/mysql on host .... I removed container mysql and restart mysql on my host machine - i run container again and there are still no database inside...

Comment: When you used `-v` option in docker command,
You should use this way: `docker run -v /var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql`.

And `/var/lib/mysql` should be MYSQL data folder both in host as well as in container. You need to set up mysql data folder in container while building it.